# Github credential (token) - update with R

Tags: r, linux, github

Following docs on install / setup config R for mgmt of new token scheme at github
but, its not working per the docs. "get" does not retreive what i save using "set" . see stdout from CLI R session:

```
> gitcreds_set()


? Enter password or token: ghp_7KKYnIVl82VN2t7jIY
-> Adding new credentials...
-> Removing credetials from cache...
-> Done.

> gitcreds_get()
Error in throw(new_error("gitcreds_no_credentials", url = url)) : 
  Could not find any credential

> gitcreds_list_helpers()
Error in new_git_error("git_error", args = args, stdout = out, status = attr(out,  : 
  System git failed:
```

i used [these docs](https://gitcreds.r-lib.org/)

git version on linux - 2.33 is the latest from package repo

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

3.6.3 above calls for git 2.9.2 so that gap and the current state of the linux re> gitcreds_list_helpers()
Error in new_git_error("git_error", args = args, stdout = out, status = attr(out,  :
System git failed:po ( git ) may be the reason for issue

-- upgrade git to 2.9.4 w manual build/install since not in repo and still getting same error

in R
system("git --version")
returns normal response == 2.9.4